# How to group by more than one variable to get 4 graphs contingent on two groupings in one plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a long-format data set (“uni_l_all”) and I’m trying to get a plot with 4 graphs, showing different trajectories contingent on high vs. low self-efficacy (“self_efficacy”, binary variable) and on training group vs. control group (“train2”, binary variable).
Grouping by self_efficacy to get two graphs works well.

But when I try to introduce “train2”, I still receive only 2 (crazy looking) graphs.
Do you have an idea how to solve this? How can I add train2 in my functions?

```
mean_uni_l_all <- group_by(uni_l_all, self_efficacy, time) %>%
summarise(ent_act = mean(ent_act, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(na.omit(mean_uni_l_all), aes(x = time, y = ent_act, colour = ese_mean, group = self_efficacy)) +
geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi Sventon - we cannot help you without a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to use faceting... does `facet_grid(self_efficacy ~ train2)` give you what you want?  If not, there's nothing more we can do without a reproducible example.